# Code on JSFiddle not working on site

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I've been looking for/playing with some jquery code that adds/removes css classes when they are in/out of view, respectively. I found this, which works perfectly from inside JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/z3xTU/417/

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if (isScrolledIntoView('.class') === true) {
            $('.class').addClass('in-view');
        }

        else {
         $('.class').removeClass('in-view');
        }

    });
```

When I posted this code to my html file, I included the link to the jquery library in the head. In addition, I added the js code in JS fiddle within the following code" 
$(document).ready(function(

JS fiddle code

});

On my page, the class on the red box isn't removed after you scroll up and it goes out of view.

http://bluebean.ca/test.html

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your JSFiddle is using jQuery 1.9.1 whereas your live code demo is on 3.2.1 (edit however that doesn't seem to make a difference)

Comment: Possibly because on jsfiddle, the document height is pretty fixed and in your browser it is not. Rather than window height, you might want to try document height instead.

Comment: Tried changing the first bit of the code to reference 'document' rather than 'window':    Made no difference.

Comment: Found the issue.   The code should be as follows:  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + document.body.clientHeight;

Comment: Update: When I actually deployed the JSfiddle code to my site, it worked 100%. For some reason, it doesn't work in isolation.